# Color change animation with a left-to-right flow

Tags: wpf

I wish to animate background color change from yellow to red with a flow from left to right. How to achieve this kind of animation in wpf?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ColorAnimation could provide the gradual change from yellow to red but because you want it to flow from left to right it might be easier to use a LinearGradient.

Set it up like this

```
GradientStopOffet, color
0, red
0, red
0, yellow
1, yellow
```

This would make the area completely yellow.

Then you animate the offset of the third gradientstop from 0 to 1
This would slowly turn the area into a gradient from red to yellow.

Once this animation has finished (or is half way) animate the second gradientstop offset from 0 to 1
This would make the entire area red.

By moving the second and third gradientstops the brush will have a 'smooth' color transition between the four gradient stops: between the first and the second, the second and the third and the third and fourth. At the beginning and at the end the transitions between the gradients stops that are at the same offset are not visible and thereby hide the color transition.

Here is an example. Play around with the starting times and durations to make the animation to your liking.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="ToRed" >
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="YellowStop"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset"
                             To="1"
                             Duration="0:0:1" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RedStop"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset"
                             BeginTime="0:0:0.5"
                             To="1"
                             Duration="0:0:1" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Click="ToRedButton_Click">To red</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <Rectangle Margin="0,50,0,0">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                     EndPoint="1,0">
                    <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                  Color="Red" />
                    <GradientStop x:Name="RedStop"
                                  Offset="0"
                                  Color="Red" />
                    <GradientStop x:Name="YellowStop"
                                  Offset="0"
                                  Color="Yellow" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                  Color="Yellow" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C# code for the button click:

```
private void ToRedButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var toRedAnimation = this.FindResource("ToRed") as Storyboard;
    if(toRedAnimation != null)
    {
        toRedAnimation.Begin();
    }
}
```

If you want a hard transition, animate the offset of the redstop at the same start time as the yellow animation.

Here is another setup, it looks different and animates the color:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="ToRed2">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MiddleStop"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset"
                             To="1"
                             Duration="0:0:1" />
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MiddleStop"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                             BeginTime="0:0:1"
                             To="Red"
                             Duration="0:0:1" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Click="ToRedButton_Click">To red</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <Rectangle Margin="0,50,0,0">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                     EndPoint="1,0">
                    <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                  Color="Red" />
                    <GradientStop x:Name="MiddleStop"
                                  Offset="0"
                                  Color="Yellow" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                  Color="Yellow" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: could you provide me with an example please

Comment: why are there 4 stops could you explain me that please

Comment: Remove them and see what happens :) It will result in abrupt color bands instead of gradients. You weren't ver specific in how the transition should look like so feel free to adjust in any way you like.

Comment: I added another way to the end of the answer. It looks a bit different. Pick any way you like

Comment: i still dont understand why 4 stops. please give me your simple explaination

Comment: When there is no colorstop at the beginning the color of the moving gradientstop would be repeated back to offset 0. By adding the stop at offest 0 you get a gradient bdetween the stops

Comment: I am stilll as smart as before.. lets say we have this kind of situation: 
0=red
1=red
0=yellow
1=yellow
why is the background drawn red and not yellow (no moving yet)

Comment: The order of the stops at the same offset is important. Just try it. In your example the first two stops determine the red color of the rectangle. The other two stops do not have any effect. Really, play with the example and read about gradient brushes.

Comment: I am trying various things out but I cannot see any pattern. Why is order important is the first one always taken?

Comment: the order is used when deciding between which stops the interpolating has to be created. Use Blend for Visual Studio to play around with the stops and drag them around to see the effect

Comment: Do you know the precedence of order when it comes to gradientstops or are you guessing? Tell me the rule which will be picken when there are multiple of the same stop offset?

Comment: Just the order in which they are added to the gradientstopcollection. In Xaml from top to bottom

Comment: well that is not true i realized that when it comes to offset = 0 the last one is being picked.... not the first one

Comment: Ah yes, depending on what side you are looking at. A at 0, B at 0.5, C at 0.5 and D at 1 will interpolate between A and B, C and C and D. It will also interpolate between B and C but that will not be visible.

Comment: I will mark your answer as theee answer but please explain me exactly what is happening with gradient stops what does interpolate mean. Please in simple english if possible. thanks

Comment: That was not the question and these comments are getting out of hand. I will see if I can find a way of adding a description to my answer that makes sense. I strongly suggest that you read in the MSDN about color animations and interpolation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms754083(v=vs.100).aspx#lineargradientbrush

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use blend. This is the most easy way to edit your xaml.